# How to echo txt file line by line to specific format with batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file like this:

```
3FPC1   00:12:34:56:78:90   192.168.6.1
3FPC2   00:12:34:56:78:91   192.168.6.2
```

I know how to read txt file line by line by using the following script

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (macip.txt) do echo %%A
pause
```

But I want to covert content to specific format like:

```
host 3FPC1 {  
  hardware ethernet 00:12:34:56:78:90;
  fixed-address 192.168.6.1;
}
host 3FPC2 {
  hardware ethernet 00:12:34:56:78:91;
  fixed-address 192.168.6.2;
}
```

How can I do it?

Is it possible to merge all the echo results and output to a txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, tell `FOR` to parse the line just read.

Read `HELP FOR` and, instead of `"tokens=*"`, use `"tokens=1,2,*"` for example

So you can

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in (macip.txt) do (
  echo host %%A {
  echo.   hardware ethernet %%B;
  echo.   fixed-address %%C;
  echo }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my modification and it can works.

```
@echo off
set filepath=C:\Users\School\Desktop\dhcp\conf
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=  " %%i in (%filepath%\macip.txt) do (
echo host %%i { > ok%%i.txt
echo. hardware ethernet %%j >> ok%%i.txt
echo. fixed-address=%%k >>ok%%i.txt
echo. } >>ok%%i.txt
echo. >>ok%%i.txt
)
copy *.txt %filepath%\yes.txt
del *.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another, perhaps simpler method:

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (macip.txt) do call :convert %%A) > yes.txt
goto :EOF

:convert
echo host %1 {
echo   hardware ethernet %2
echo   fixed-address %3
echo }
```